# How to get date and time result zero when both the times are equal?

Tags: c#

I have two times as follows :

```
DateTime time1=Datetimepicker1.value;
DateTime time2=file1.creationtime;
```

time1 and time2 both has date and time is showing 12-31-2014 15:00:33
but when i am compairing both the times it is giving false result as :

```
int result=DateTime.Compare(time1,time2);
```

result value is not 0.
How?

Comment: And what is the problem? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
    public void Search()
    {
        DateTime minimiumDate;
        DateTime maximumDate;

        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
        {
            DateTime fileDate = DateTime.Parse(file);
            if(fileDate > minimiumDate && maximumDate > fileDate)
                //dostuff
        }
    }
```